# Why does my Rx.NET observable appear to produce its entire sequence twice?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, mspec, ncrunch

I have a randomly failing unit test which I'm at a loss to explain. This involves an observable sequence using Rx.NET and an extension method that I made to transform the sequence. First, let me show how the test fails:

```
Machine.Specifications.SpecificationException:   Expected: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]:
{
  [8],
  [10],
  [11]
}

  But was:  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]:
{
  [8],
  [10],
  [11],
  [8],
  [10],
  [11]
}
```

OK, so you see, I get the entire sequence twice instead of once. Here's the test:

```
[Subject(typeof(ObservableExtensions), "Shutter Current Readings")]
internal class when_a_shutter_current_reading_is_received
    {
    Establish context = () => source = "Z8\nZ10\nZ11\n".ToObservable();
    Because of = () => source
        .ShutterCurrentReadings().Trace("Unbelievable")
        .SubscribeAndWaitForCompletion(item => elementHistory.Add(item));
    It should_receive_the_current_readings = () => elementHistory.ShouldEqual(expectedElements);
    static List<int> elementHistory = new List<int>();
    static List<int> expectedElements = new List<int> {8, 10, 11};
    static IObservable<char> source;

    }
```

`SubscribeAndWaitForCompletion()` is an extension method defined as follows:

```
public static void SubscribeAndWaitForCompletion<T>(this IObservable<T> sequence, Action<T> observer)
    {
    var sequenceComplete = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    var subscription = sequence.Subscribe(
        onNext: observer,
        onCompleted: () => sequenceComplete.Set()
        );
    sequenceComplete.WaitOne();
    subscription.Dispose();
    sequenceComplete.Dispose();
    }
```

You'll notice there's a `.Trace()` call in there, and another one inside the extension method, and this produces logging about the observable sequence via NLog, Here's the trace output:

```
20:43:43.1547|DEBUG|c__DisplayClass0_1`1|Unbelievable[1]: Subscribe()
20:43:43.1547|DEBUG|c__DisplayClass0_1`1|ShutterCurrent[1]: Subscribe()
20:43:43.1547|DEBUG|c__DisplayClass0_1`1|ShutterCurrent[1]: OnNext(8)
20:43:43.1547|DEBUG|c__DisplayClass0_1`1|Unbelievable[1]: OnNext(8)
20:43:43.1547|DEBUG|c__DisplayClass0_1`1|ShutterCurrent[1]: OnNext(10)
20:43:43.1547|DEBUG|c__DisplayClass0_1`1|Unbelievable[1]: OnNext(10)
20:43:43.1547|DEBUG|c__DisplayClass0_1`1|ShutterCurrent[1]: OnNext(11)
20:43:43.1547|DEBUG|c__DisplayClass0_1`1|Unbelievable[1]: OnNext(11)
20:43:43.1547|DEBUG|c__DisplayClass0_1`1|ShutterCurrent[1]: OnCompleted()
20:43:43.1547|DEBUG|c__DisplayClass0_1`1|Unbelievable[1]: OnCompleted()
20:43:43.1547|DEBUG|c__DisplayClass0_1`1|Unbelievable[1]: Dispose()
20:43:43.1547|DEBUG|c__DisplayClass0_1`1|ShutterCurrent[1]: Dispose()
Child test failed
```

This is pretty much what I would expect. I get one trace output from inside my extension method, then another on the transformed sequence outside the extension method. Each element in the sequence flows through the system exactly once, just as expected. And yet, I get the entire sequence captured *twice* in my test.

I had better provide the extension method so we can see what it does. Here it is:

```
    public static IObservable<int> ShutterCurrentReadings(this IObservable<char> source)
        {
        const string shutterCurrentPattern = @"^Z(?<Current>\d{1,2})[^0-9]";
        var shutterCurrentRegex =
            new Regex(shutterCurrentPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
        var buffers = source.Publish(s => s.BufferByPredicates(p => p == 'Z', q => !char.IsDigit(q)));
        var shutterCurrentValues = from buffer in buffers
                                   let message = new string(buffer.ToArray())
                                   let patternMatch = shutterCurrentRegex.Match(message)
                                   where patternMatch.Success
                                   let shutterCurrent = int.Parse(patternMatch.Groups["Current"].Value)
                                   select shutterCurrent;
        return shutterCurrentValues.Trace("ShutterCurrent");
        }
```

So the intent here is to pick out readings from a current sensor from within the data stream. The readings are in the format Znn (literal 'Z' followed by one or two decimal digits followed by a newline. The extension method transforms the raw input character sequence into a sequence of integers representing current readings. The filter uses the Rx `Buffer` operator to buffer up characters that it thinks might be valid sensor readings. The buffer is opened when a 'Z' character is seen and closed when a non-digit character is seen. This is double checked by matching and parsing in a regular expression and then if the result passes all that it is converted to an integer and emitted in the output sequence.

Can anyone see why I might be getting double-data in my results?

Update: additional code relevant to the investigation.

```
    public static IObservable<IList<char>> BufferByPredicates(this IObservable<char> source,
        Predicate<char> bufferOpening, Predicate<char> bufferClosing)
        {
        return source.Buffer(source.Where(c => bufferOpening(c)), x => source.Where(c => bufferClosing(c)));
        }
```

The `Trace` extension method is found in NuGet package `TA.ASCOM.ReactiveCommunications` (one of mine) but here's the source:

```
    public static IObservable<TSource> Trace<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, string name)
        {
        var log = LogManager.GetLogger(name);
        var id = 0;
        return Observable.Create<TSource>(observer =>
            {
            var idClosure = ++id;
            Action<string, object> trace = (m, v) => log.Debug("{0}[{1}]: {2}({3})", name, idClosure, m, v);
            trace("Subscribe", "");
            var disposable = source.Subscribe(
                v =>
                    {
                    trace("OnNext", v);
                    observer.OnNext(v);
                    },
                e =>
                    {
                    trace("OnError", "");
                    observer.OnError(e);
                    },
                () =>
                    {
                    trace("OnCompleted", "");
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                    });
            return () =>
                {
                trace("Dispose", "");
                disposable.Dispose();
                };
            });
        }
```

I suspect I may have copied this code from someone else but I don't seem to have made a note of who.

Comment: What happens if you comment out `elementHistory.Add(item)`?

Comment: Can you post the code for `SubscribeAndWaitForCompletion`? Or where it's from?

Comment: Also, `elementHistory` is static. Can you change it to an instance field?

Comment: @Shlomo I'm afraid that I have no choice about the static, it's a restriction imposed by MSpec because the Establish, Because and It delegates are field initializers so they can only access static fields. I suspect this could be a factor in the problem but I can't quite put my finget on why.

Comment: @Shlomo Added code for `SubscribeAndWaitForCompletion` extension method as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Here's a way to mock the problem up in LinqPad, without using the MSpec/NChrunch (?) runner:

```
void Main()
{
    //static initializers
    List<int> expectedElements = new List<int> { 8, 10, 11 };
    List<int> elementHistory = new List<int>();
    IObservable<char> source;

    //simulated continuous running of MSpec test
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {

        //establish
        source = "Z8\nZ10\nZ11\n".ToObservable();

        //because
        source
            .ShutterCurrentReadings()
            .Trace("Unbelievable")
            .SubscribeAndWaitForCompletion(item => elementHistory.Add(item));

        //it
        elementHistory.Dump(i.ToString()); //Linqpad
        if(elementHistory.Count > 3)
            throw new Exception("Assert.ShouldNotHappen");
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IObservable<int> ShutterCurrentReadings(this IObservable<char> source)
    {
        const string shutterCurrentPattern = @"^Z(?<Current>\d{1,2})[^0-9]";
        var shutterCurrentRegex =
            new Regex(shutterCurrentPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
        var buffers = source.Publish(s => s.BufferByPredicates(p => p == 'Z', q => !char.IsDigit(q)));
        var shutterCurrentValues = from buffer in buffers
                                   let message = new string(buffer.ToArray())
                                   let patternMatch = shutterCurrentRegex.Match(message)
                                   where patternMatch.Success
                                   let shutterCurrent = int.Parse(patternMatch.Groups["Current"].Value)
                                   select shutterCurrent;
        return shutterCurrentValues.Trace("ShutterCurrent");
    }

    public static void SubscribeAndWaitForCompletion<T>(this IObservable<T> sequence, Action<T> observer)
    {
        var sequenceComplete = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var subscription = sequence.Subscribe(
            onNext: observer,
            onCompleted: () => sequenceComplete.Set()
            );
        sequenceComplete.WaitOne();
        subscription.Dispose();
        sequenceComplete.Dispose();
    }

    public static IObservable<TSource> Trace<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, string name)
    {
        var log = LogManager.GetLogger(name);
        var id = 0;
        return Observable.Create<TSource>(observer =>
            {
                var idClosure = ++id;
                Action<string, object> trace = (m, v) => log.Debug("{0}[{1}]: {2}({3})", name, idClosure, m, v);
                trace("Subscribe", "");
                var disposable = source.Subscribe(
                    v =>
                        {
                            trace("OnNext", v);
                            observer.OnNext(v);
                        },
                    e =>
                        {
                            trace("OnError", "");
                            observer.OnError(e);
                        },
                    () =>
                        {
                            trace("OnCompleted", "");
                            observer.OnCompleted();
                        });
                return () =>
                    {
                        trace("Dispose", "");
                        disposable.Dispose();
                    };
            });
    }

    public static IObservable<IList<char>> BufferByPredicates(this IObservable<char> source,
        Predicate<char> bufferOpening, Predicate<char> bufferClosing)
    {
        return source.Buffer(source.Where(c => bufferOpening(c)), x => source.Where(c => bufferClosing(c)));
    }
}
```

This fails, like your scenario.

My best suggestion for fixing it would be to move initialization of `elementHistory` to the `Establish` step. You can also move the `source` variable away from the establish, so your test would look like this:

```
internal class when_a_shutter_current_reading_is_received
{
    Establish context = () => elementHistory = new List<int>();
    Because of = () => "Z8\nZ10\nZ11\n".ToObservable()
        .ShutterCurrentReadings()
        .Trace("Unbelievable")
        .SubscribeAndWaitForCompletion(item => elementHistory.Add(item));
    It should_receive_the_current_readings = () => elementHistory.ShouldEqual(expectedElements);
    static List<int> elementHistory;
    static List<int> expectedElements = new List<int> { 8, 10, 11 };

}
```

You may also want to look at `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing` which provides some more robust testing on Rx queries, though it wouldn't read as simply as your tests.

---

Old Answer:

I can't compile your code due to missing `Trace`, `ShouldEqual` and `BufferByPredicates` functions. If they come from an external source, please document where.

I'm guessing the problem stems from the `BufferByPredicates` implementation, the `Trace` implementation, the lack of `Connect` after the `Publish`, or the static `elementHistory`.

My best guess is the static `elementHistory`: If that test is run twice concurrently, you have a race condition and it's possible you would end up with double results (`Establish` runs twice, then `Because` runs twice, then `It` would fail).

---

Comment: I'm sorry I made you ask for the extra code. I thought it was going to be quite self-contained but I was wrong. `ShouldEqual` comes from `Machine.Specifications.Should` package, the other two are mine and I'll update the question with them. Thanks for your persistence, I know it is a big ask. I suspect you are right about the test running twice but it shouldn't do that, and these tests have been working fine, then suddenly they start failing. Thinking about it I also updated NCrunch a few days ago so it might be a runner issue..

Comment: Posted an edit. I hope it solves your problem. I have no experience with MSpec, in fact hadn't heard of it prior to yesterday. Interesting project.